# Bike transport from Haridwar to Bangalore

Tags: trains, india, bicycles

Can anyone help me that how can I transport my bike from Haridwar to Bangalore? Are there  trains that have this facility?

Answer (score 4):

https://sr.indianrailways.gov.in/cris//uploads/files/1479448272390-parcel-rules-two-wheeler-booking.pdf

> There are two options to transport a two wheeler by train. The two wheeler can be booked as luggage if you are travelling by the same train. If you are not travelling by same train, the two wheeler can be booked as parcel.

The link talks about motorbikes but the process is very similar for bicycles. Of course, the guidelines for fuel etc do not apply and the charges might be lower.